# Reading a file with tokens runs only once

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to read a file with some tokens, using fgets and strtok_s, I wanted to use strtok, but it's not safe, and I couldn't find any good example in how to use it. After some checks I've made, what's happening it's reading from the file only the words such as the first word before of the token (i.e. if the string is "1,2,3,4,5,1" and the token is ",", so it would read 1 twice in the same loop, and would exit the while loop.
The code:

```
int val_to_add = 0;
TreeNode * head = new TreeNode(NIL,NIL,NIL,NIL);
FILE * fp;
char line[MAX_LINE];
char *pstr;
errno_t err;
char * context = NULL;


if (argc == 1)
{
     //There was no file option.
}
else
{
    if ((err = fopen_s(&fp, argv[1], "r")) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR!\nCannot open file '%s'.\n",argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE, fp) != NULL)
    {
        pstr = strtok_s(line, ",", &context);
        val_to_add = atoi(pstr);
        add_treenode(head, val_to_add);
        printf("%s\n",pstr);
    }
}
```

Why is the loop is working only once?

Comment: If there are multiple tokens in a line, shouldn't you be calling `strtok_s` more than once per line?

Comment: I have an unknown number of tokens per line, and I remmber that's in college I've always used this line, then what should I use?

Comment: You need two loops, one loop reads each line and the second loop (inside the first) reads each token on the line.

Comment: You're right, I've forgotten that strtok is reading a line, not inbetween tokens.

Comment: Thanks a lot  :)

Comment: Try `std::string` and `std::getline(std::cin, line, ',');`